# Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2021-06 Cannot find class paths for jars

Tags: java, eclipse

I have built a new machine and installed a fresh version of eclipse (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2021-06). If I run an old project it works. If I make a new project I the following error.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/crl/CRLibs/DBI
at EnvList.(EnvList.java:143)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.crl.CRLibs.DBI
There are no errors in the code.
The build path looks like:

[image: New Build Path]

```
Line:143 is: static DBI db = new DBI();
```

DBI is defined in the crlibs jar.
In my old Eclipse (Oxygen) the build path looks like:
[image: Oxygen Build Path]

I tried adding the crlibs jar to the Classpath, but it will not let me save it (all boxes grayed out).
Now this code is copy of a template I use. The original runs just fine and its build path looks like the one from Oxygen.

If I comment out this line it will give the same error at the next library access.
It appears that the Class paths to the library are not being included.
Note The library was built with Oxygen. Do I need to rebuild it with the new version and if so will it then still work for all the code build with Oxygen.
How do I fix this?

Note:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

And
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)
Build id: 20210612-2011

EDIT:
Here is the .classpath file.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-16">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Documents and Settings/Cliff/libs/crlibs.jar" sourcepath="E:/Documents and Settings/Cliff/Libs_src/CRLibs/src/net/crl/CRLibs">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/E:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Cliff/Libs_src/CRLibs/CRLibs/doc/"/>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

The path to the jar is there?

EDIT2
[image]
The command line:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file and does deleting it fix your issue? It could also be due to using Java 16 instead of Java 8 (since Java 9 there is no 100% backward compatibility anymore).

Comment: @howlger Don't have a module-info.java.  I did try changing Java #s, no change.  thanks

Comment: @abra Eclipse shows no errors.  As I said, it runs without error in the old Eclipse.

Comment: @abra Yes. You can see the library's build path in the figure 1. See edit2 for run dependences and the command line.

Comment: Mixing classpath and module-path never works for me. I always put everything in module-path.

Comment: @abra OK, how do I do that? In Oxygen there was no module-path, that I ever saw.  Eclipse put things where they are and I have not been able to make any changes to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the figure below

[image]

You must delete the jar from *Modulepath* THEN add it to the *Classpath*. The JRE seems just fine in the Modulepath. Once my library is in the classpath the code works.